# failed to find target with hash string 'android-23

Tags: android-sdk

I got my android installed, but i have "android-24" and when i am building my ionic application. It needs "android-23" . It gives below error :-

```
failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'
```

How can i add another folder of "android-23" in Android "platforms" folder.

Thanks

Comment: You need to update `sdk` in your Android Studio. Choose `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`. Then update `sdk`

Comment: i have "android-24" and i need "android-23"

Comment: Got it installed via "SDK" )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you see message like below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAjvv.png]

click on `Open Android SDK Manager` and choose libs version to install. In your case it is `23`.

Another way, as you have installed `android-24` is to update `app/build.gradle file` as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

you can also update your Android support libraries dependencies to `24.2.1`, but this step is optionally.